# What is the minimum number of edges one has to remove for a graph to have no odd-length cycles

Tags: graph-theory

**Question**:

Suppose I have a graph with $n$ edges and the number of vertices is unknown, what is the minimum number of edges I need to remove in order to make sure any graph with $n$ edges will no longer contain any odd-length cycles?

For instance, if $n=3$, then the minimum number of edges I will have to remove is $1$. This is because for $n=3$, the only graph that will have an odd-length cycles is a triangle, in which case I can just remove one of the edges to make such graph odd-length-cycles free.

I hope my questions make sense so far.

**My thoughts and 'reasoning'**:

I had some thoughts regarding this problem and I tempted to say the minimum edges I need to remove is $\frac{n}{3}$ in order for any graph with $n$ edges odd-length-cycles free.

This is because I think the most odd-length cycles a graph with $n$ vertices can make is $n \choose 3$ and if there are two odd-length cycles that share an edge, we can just delete that edge to remove these two cycles at once. So I think the problem just reduces to the fact that a graph with $n$ edges can make at most $\frac{n}{3}$ disjoint triangles? Hence if I can remove an edge from each disjoint triangle then I will be done?

I know that my argument is very likely to be incorrect but how should one approach this problem?

I do not have a very deep background in graph theory. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You may find this paper to be of interest: http://combinatorica.hu/~p_erdos/1988-12.pdf. It addresses a more difficult version of your problem, but contains the simple version (the answer given by bof) in the second paragraph (along with a reference). Of particular interest is that much stronger results can be made of graphs with girth $\geq 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A graph with no odd cycles is called a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) because the vertex set of such a graph can be partitioned into two sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ so that every edge has one endpoint in $V_1$ and the other in $V_2$.

**Proposition.** Any graph $G=(V,E)$ has a bipartite subgraph which contains at least half the edges of $G$. (In other words, if $G$ has $n$ edges, then $G$ can be made bipartite by removing at most $n/2$ edges.)

[**P.S.** A comment by user [Paralyzed_by_Time](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/736448/paralyzed-by-time) provided references for this observation: [Paul Erdős, Ralph Faudree, János Pach, and Joel Spencer, How to make a graph bipartite, *J. Combin. Theory Ser. B* 45 (1988), 86–98](http://combinatorica.hu/~p_erdos/1988-12.pdf) and (apparently the original reference) P. Erdős, On some extremal problems in graph theory, *Israel J. Math.* 3 (1965), 113–116.]

**Proof.** Partition $V$ into two sets $V_1,V_2$ in a way that maximizes the number of edges that cross between $V_1$ and $V_2$. Note that each vertex has at least as many neighbors on the other side of the partition as on its own side; otherwise moving $v$ to the other side would increase the number of cross-edges, contradicting the assumed maximality of the partition. From this it easily follows that at least half the edges of $G$ cross between $V_1$ and $V_2$, i.e., the bipartite graph with those edges contains at least half the edges of $G$.

In general we can't do too much better than delete half the edges, because of the following example. The complete graph $K_t$ has $n=\binom t2=\frac{t^2-t}2$ edges, and its largest bipartite subgraph has $\lceil\frac t2\rceil\cdot\lfloor\frac t2\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{t^2}4\rfloor$ edges, so we have to delete almost half the edges of $K_t$ to get a bipartite graph.

Comment: With no information on the number of vertices I don't think we can do much better indeed. It is worth noting however that if we know the number of vertices, then if $G$ has $2v$ vertices it contains a bipartite subgraph with at least $\frac{nv}{2v-1}$ edges ; while if $G$ has $2v+1$ vertices then it contains a bipartite subgraphs with at least $\frac{n(v+1)}{2v+1}$ edges. These bounds are tight for complete graphs.